# How would I make one turtle labyrinth fit into another turtle labyrinth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make one turtle labyrinth fit into another one. Specifically, I want to make red (turtle u) fit into orange (turtle t) and I'm quite stumped.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.color("orange")
t.pensize(3)
t.speed(0)

u = turtle.Turtle()
u.color("red")
u.pensize(3)
u.speed(0)

x = 10
y = 10

for i in range(360):
    t.forward(x)
    t.left(90)
    x = x + 10

    u.forward(y)
    u.left(90)
    y = y + 5
```

Comment: Here is OP's code on repl.it, for those who dont have python + turtle: https://repl.it/repls/PossibleSneakyScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the turtles to not be overlapping, they can't start in the same place. You want to start them off in different locations for starters. After that, try doing it step by step and seeing if what you're getting translates to what you think you should be getting, instead of doing all 360 steps really fast. Setting the pen speed slower should also help you. You have to plan the steps before writing the code, but seeing your steps will help you debug them.

Comment: Good point. I'll see if I can make it so turtle U starts a bit further up

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! Code if anyone's interested.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.color("orange")
t.pensize(3)
t.speed(0)

u = turtle.Turtle()
u.color("red")
u.pensize(3)
u.speed(0)

u.penup()
u.setpos(3,10)
u.left(90)
u.pendown()

x = 10
y = 0

for i in range(360):
    t.forward(x)
    t.left(90)
    x = x + 10

    u.forward(y)
    u.left(90)
    y = y + 10
```